# Featured Products

Tags: magento-1.6, featured-product

I have a grid of 3 featured products on the home page but I don't know how to change the products, please could someone guide me.
I am not a developer and the guy who was looking after the web has left.

Comment: This is probably some sort of category you have to fill with products. But since it's not a default Magento feature it's hard to help you with your question without any extra info

Comment: I have checked and unfortunately there isn't a category for the featured products. Any other ideas?

Comment: It might be something under system > configuration or a widget, static block, product attribute. There are quite a lot of ways a developer could go about building something like this

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing in those either.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest looking for a new Magento developer that can help you out with maintenance. There is very little to go on here to help you